# Running batch file from c# code works in local environment, but not working after upload on server

Tags: c#, batch-file, jar

I have a "batch" file which internally calls "jar" file and enters some values into database from that jar file.
Now I want to call this "batch" file from asp.net mvc4 C# code.

It works fine in local environment.

But it is not working after upload on server.

Comment: Can you include some more info, like the batch file contents (at least near the call) and the true locations of the files you are calling?

Comment: java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 -o true
PAUSE


This is the code of my batch file.
The arguments are passed from c# code and it takes relative path.
There is also no space in any path.

Comment: And what happens when you execute it?

Comment: It is not running on server.
But it is running on local environment.

Comment: One more thing I would like to add is, if I give physical path in batch file and run it via double click on server also, then it is executing properly.

Comment: Scenario 1 : Running batch file via double click on local environment after setting physical path : Works fine.
Scenario 2 : Running batch file from c# on local environment with dynamic parameters : Works fine.
Scenario 3 : Running batch file via double click on server after setting physical path : Works fine.
Scenario 4 : Running batch file from c# on server after hosting on IIS with dynamic parameters : DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: I'm looking more for the exception information, but based on your last comment it seems to definitely be path related.  Is the jar in the same folder as the page it's being called from and the batch file'

Comment: I have also put try...catch in C# and logging exceptions into temporary text file.
But there also there is no log found.
So from C# the exception is not thrown.

Comment: What about Chris Schubert's question?